# Killed process is getting back again using GetProcessesByName

Tags: c#, process

In my c# windows application, I have written below code to run the process and kill any process if running before starting the c# application , and if running kill it and start it again by my c# application.

```
//Finding TestApp
Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("TestApp");
If any TesyApp running before kill it
if (pname.Length != 0 && this.processId == 0)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < pname.Length; i++)
   { 
    pname[i].Kill();
   }
//Again find the TestApp
 pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("TestApp");                        
}
//If not found start the process
if (pname.Length == 0 )
{
---
process.Start();
this.processId = process.Id;
}
```

My issue is , before i run my c# application if any TestApp(Its different applcation developed by flex) application is running kill it, and restrt it by the c#. If i debug my code everything is working fine.
But if i run my c# code not in debug mode then after,
pname[i].Kill(); line 
pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("TestApp"); this is finding again. So length become 1 and c# unable to start it and exits the if condition.
if (pname.Length == 0 )
    {
    --
}

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pname[i].WaitForExit()` after `pname[i].Kill()`to make sure it has been killed. i.e.:

```
if (pname.Length != 0 && this.processId == 0)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < pname.Length; i++)
  { 
    pname[i].Kill();
    pname[i].WaitForExit();
  }
  //Again find the TestApp
  pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("TestApp");                        
}
```

`Process.Kill` is asynchronous, so it doesn't wait for the actual process to be killed.

The fact that it works while debugging is probably just because it takes more time, so it allows the process to be killed.